# Solr DataImportHandler - Transform XML Field

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

A column on my DB (which is synced to my SOLR repo) is XML and looks something like:

```
<Party>
    <StartDate>2013-12-31T06:00:00</StartDate>
</Party>
```

In SOLR, this is stored in a `type="string"` field and everything works fine.

Now, however, I wish to extract the `<StartDate>` value from the XML and store it in a standalone `string` or `date` field (no preference as of yet).

What's the best way to solve this?

My solution is to attach a JavaScript transformer that will parse the XML using normal string functions (i.e. indexOf and substring). This doesn't seem very pretty though. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use nested entity combined with the switch of data source. For the inner data source, you need to use [FieldReaderDataSource](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#FieldReaderDataSource) with XPathEntityProcessor handling the mapping of the XML to the target value. I think your date is already in the correct format to map directly to the data type. But if it is not, you need to use [DateFormatTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DateFormatTransformer) on the inner entity.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [DateFormatTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DateFormatTransformer) that is available with the Solr [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler).

Comment: Yes, but he needs to get to that inner XML value first. It is nested.